# Unifi USG - Route one device through WAN2 and port forward

Tags: routes

On my newly installed Unifi USG (Unifi Security Gateway/Controller) at home i have two static IP Internets connected to :

> WAN1 (ETH0) : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

> WAN2 (ETH2) : yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Whole home network is routed by default via WAN1, with WAN2 set as 'failover' by default in USG.

I need to:

- route a single lan ip address (192.168.1.119) through WAN2,
- enable a port forward there on 22(ssh) -> 192.168.1.119

Here is the CLI dump i have in USG:

```
UNIROUTER:~$ ip route
default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0  proto zebra 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy



Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down
Interface    IP Address                        S/L  Description                 
---------    ----------                        ---  -----------                 
eth0         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24                u/u  WAN                         
eth1         192.168.1.1/24                    u/u  LAN                         
eth2         yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/24                u/u  WAN2                        
lo           127.0.0.1/8                       u/u                              
             ::1/128
```

I have no idea how to set it up, and have already found i can't do it via web..
Can you help me out, to set it up please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, minutes after - i found the solution, lucky me ;-)

```
#ROUTING
configure
set protocols static table 5 route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
set firewall modify LOAD_BALANCE rule 2640 action modify
set firewall modify LOAD_BALANCE rule 2640 modify table 5
set firewall modify LOAD_BALANCE rule 2640 source address 192.168.1.119
set firewall modify LOAD_BALANCE rule 2640 protocol all
commit;exit



#PORTFWD
configure
set service nat rule 4000 description "COTX"
set service nat rule 4000 destination address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
set service nat rule 4000 destination port 22
set service nat rule 4000 inbound-interface eth2
set service nat rule 4000 inside-address address 192.168.1.119
set service nat rule 4000 inside-address port 22
set service nat rule 4000 protocol tcp
set service nat rule 4000 type destination
commit;exit
```